# Regular expression matching "dictionary words"

Tags: java, regex

I'm a Java user but I'm new to regular expressions.

I just want to have a tiny expression that, given a word (we assume that the string is only one word), answers with a boolean, telling if the word is valid or not.

An example... I want to catch all words that is plausible to be in a dictionary... So, i just want words with chars from a-z A-Z, an hyphen (for example: man-in-the-middle) and an apostrophe (like I'll  or Tiffany's).

Valid words:

- `"food"`
- `"RocKet"`
- `"man-in-the-middle"`
- `"kahsdkjhsakdhakjsd"`
- `"JESUS"`, etc.

Non-valid words:

- `"gipsy76"`
- `"www.google.com"`
- `"me@gmail.com"`
- `"745474"`
- `"+-x/"`, etc.

I use this code, but it won't gave the correct answer:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[A-Za-z&-&']");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
System.out.println(m.matches());
```

What's wrong with my regex?

Comment: Isn't it a bit naïve (perhaps even blasé) to assume that words only contain ASCII letters?

Comment: depends on the language (The one he speeks, not codes) :) And I think, as long as you just code for fun, there is no problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Add a `+` after the expression to say "one or more of those characters":
- Escape the hyphen with `\` (or put it last).
- Remove those `&` characters:

Here's the code:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[A-Za-z'-]+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
System.out.println(m.matches());
```

---

Complete test:

```
String[] ok = {"food","RocKet","man-in-the-middle","kahsdkjhsakdhakjsd","JESUS"};
String[] notOk = {"gipsy76", "www.google.com", "me@gmail.com", "745474","+-x/" };

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[A-Za-z'-]+");

for (String shouldMatch : ok)
    if (!p.matcher(shouldMatch).matches())
        System.out.println("Error on: " + shouldMatch);

for (String shouldNotMatch : notOk)
    if (p.matcher(shouldNotMatch).matches())
        System.out.println("Error on: " + shouldNotMatch);
```

(Produces no output.)

Comment: Why do you use the ' at the end of you regex?

Comment: It should match for instance `"Tiffany's"`

Comment: `Pattern.compile("[A-Za-z'-]+")`

Comment: Maybe also add ^ and $ to confirm that it is only one word. `Pattern.compile("^[A-Za-z'-]+$")`.

Comment: @XenoLupus, doesn't matter as he is using `matches`. (It would matter if he used `find` for instance, but why would he?)

Comment: @aioobe: I wasn't aware that ´matches´ tries to match against the entire input.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

`"[A-Za-z'-]+"`

Comment: Note that with a `*` it matches the empty string, `""` which presumably is not a word that can occur in a dictionary ;)

Answer (score 0):

But "-word" and "word-" are not valid. So you can uses this pattern:

```
WORD_EXP = "^[A-Za-z]+(-[A-Za-z]+)*$"
```

Answer (score 0):

> Regex - /^([a-zA-Z]*('|-)?[a-zA-Z]+)*/

You can use above regex if you don't want successive "'" or "-".
It will give you accurate matching your text.
It accepts 
   man-in-the-middle
   asd'asdasd'asd

It rejects following string
man--in--midle
asdasd''asd

Answer (score -1):

Hi Aloob please check with this, Bit lengthy, might be having shorter version of this, Still...

```
[A-z]*||[[A-z]*[-]*]*||[[A-z]*[-]*[']*]*
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by this (it's obviously not a valid/working regular expression)? What's with all the double slashes, double pipes, nested brackets etc.? What do you think `[A-z]` does?

Comment: @TimPietzcker Ok guys, I was just trying to get it, I apologize for this answer. It did work for me, thts why I just pasted it. [A-z] means it will compare both case letters. DOuble pipes means 'Or'.  Sorry...

Comment: `[A-z]` is wrong. You need `[A-Za-z]` because there are several characters between `Z` and `a` that aren't letters. Single pipes mean "or" in a regex, not double pipes. And you can't nest brackets like that; also `*` is treated as a literal asterisk inside a character class etc. etc...